# Interpreting the decimal point in arhithmetic calculations in Vim

Tags: vim

It seems to me that all of a sudden Vim doesn't recognize the decimal point anymore.

For example, if I do a

> : echo 22.0/3.0

then I receive a

> 2200

This is probably because Vim sees the dot as a string concatenator and so calculates
`22 . (0/3) . 0` which is `22 . 0 . 0`  which then is `2200`.

I can confirm this suspicion by doing a `:echo 3.9` and when I receive a `39`.

I am pretty sure that I had this working correctly (whereas correctly means: as I expected). So, have I changed some setting or something?

Thanks / Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Vim 7.2, gVim as well. You explicitly have to surround the numbers with quotes to get the result you posted. I suggest you upgrade your Vim.

Comment: Sure enought, I had this occurence on another computer with still Vim 7.1 installed.